# Given that the western world is built on slavery and colonialism, to what extent are we obligated to refrain from benefiting from its services?

Tags: halacha

How many degrees removed do we have to be from actual exploitation, robbery and murder before we can benefit from products of these violations, even by a gentile? The prosperity we enjoy in the west has been built on the backs of these crimes, albeit from gentiles. Specifically, Toronto was the territories of the Mississauga before the white man forced its surrender. This is theft under the Noachide laws. A more specific question will be given that Toronto runs on stolen land, reparations not yet paid, what is our obligations as residents who buy and deal business with thieves, or buyers of thieves?

Answer (score 3):

Conquest and slavery is not forbidden for non-Jewish countries. There is no inherent prohibition from benefiting from these actions.

A good follow up question would be what, halachicly, is a country. The East India Company or may not count as a country.

Comment: That’s simply not true. The seven noahide laws prohibit coercive sales, outright thievery and murderous robbery.

Comment: That's on a personal level.